# Unable to Create View from PHP but can from phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, sql-view

I am working on a PHP installation script that will create the required database, tables, and views in MySQL. When I run the script in Internet Explorer, it returns a blank screen (as expected if there were no errors).

When I go look at my database in phpMyAdmin though, I see all the tables, but the view does not exist. When I run the same `CREATE VIEW` SQL statement through phpMyAdmin's SQL window, the view creates as expected.

I have plenty of experience with SQL, but I am brand new to PHP and phpMyAdmin. Why will the view not create from the PHP script when the tables do?

PHP script:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Install Flashcard Script</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='custom.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>

    <?php
        $host = "localhost";
        $user = "root";
        $password = "";
        $database = "FLASHCARD";

        $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $password) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
        $mysqli->query("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS " . $database) or die($mysqli->error);
        $mysqli->query("CREATE DATABASE " . $database) or die($mysqli->error);

        $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

        $mysqli->query("CREATE TABLE COURSES (
                            COURSE_ID INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
                            COURSE_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                            COURSE_DESC TEXT NOT NULL,
                            DATE_CREATED DATETIME NOT NULL,
                            CREATED_BY BIGINT(20)
                            )") or die($mysqli->error);

        $mysqli->query("CREATE TABLE COURSE_SUBJECTS (
                            SUBJ_ID INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                            COURSE_ID INT(6),
                            SUBJ_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                            SUBJ_DESC TEXT,
                            DATE_CREATED DATETIME NOT NULL,
                            CREATED_BY BIGINT(20)
                            )") or die($mysqli->error);

        $mysqli->query("CREATE TABLE SUBJECT_DECKS (
                            DECK_ID INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                            SUBJ_ID INT(6) NOT NULL,
                            DECK_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                            DECK_DESC TEXT,
                            DATE_CREATED DATETIME NOT NULL,
                            CREATED_BY BIGINT(20)
                            )") or die($mysqli->error); 

        $mysqli->query("CREATE VIEW DECK_VIEW AS
                            SELECT 
                                c.COURSE_ID,
                                cs.SUBJ_ID,
                                sd.DECK_ID,
                                c.COURSE_NAME,
                                c.COURSE_DESC,
                                cs.SUBJ_NAME,
                                cs.SUBJ_DESC,
                                sd.DECK_NAME,
                                sd.DECK_DESC
                            FROM COURSES c
                            LEFT JOIN COURSE_SUBJECTS cs ON cs.COURSE_ID = c.COURSE_ID
                            LEFT JOIN SUBJECT_DECKS sd on sd.SUBJ_ID = cs.SUBJ_ID
                            ORDER BY COURSE_NAME, SUBJ_NAME, DECK_NAME
                            )") or die($mysqli->error);

    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Edit

I was missing an error catch statement on the `CREATE VIEW`. Now that I added that in there, it gave me the following error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 16

Line 16 corresponds to `$database = "FLASHCARD";`. What does that mean?

Comment: Enable error reporting. You're checking for errors on the queries except for the last one. Add `mysqli_error($mysqli)` to that and see if there are errors.

Comment: I added it in, and it gave me this error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 16`. That corresponds to the line `$database = "FLASHCARD";`. What does that tell me?

Comment: You forgot a bracket in the last query. Edit: Try `CREATE VIEW DECK_VIEW AS (
                            SELECT`.

Comment: Btw, line 16 is not what you think it is, it is in the query because of the missing bracket, and not `$database = "FLASHCARD";`. The line count comes from PHP/Query.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner that did it, thanks! I guess I just needed another set of eyes on it. Thanks for explaining the line 16 thing too.

Comment: You're most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 16 is not coming from what you think, it's in the query itself.

You missed a bracket in the last query and should have used `mysqli_error($mysqli)` on the query there also.

So change your code in there to

```
CREATE VIEW DECK_VIEW AS ( SELECT...
                         ^ // right there
```

Comment: *Cheers!* @SandPiper Yeah, sometimes another pair of eyes helps, glad I could help. Edit: Ah, you deleted the comment, no worries :-)

Comment: Or, the other way around -- No parens needed around the `SELECT ...`.